# conflict with currfile and doclicense causing ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]

Tags: capacity, stack

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,scheme = plain]{ctexart}
%%% 28 April 2022
%%%%% packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tasks}
%% font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %% changes font to sans-serif
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
%%%%%% floor function
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%% License
\usepackage[type= {CC},modifier= {by-nc-nd},version= {4.0}]{doclicense}
%% filename and path
\usepackage{currfile}
%% fancy header and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totpages}
%% SUPER IMPORTANT
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09]
%%      -    QR    -     %%
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{background}
%%background - go to back%%
\makeatletter
\def\AM@AddToShipoutPicture{\AddToShipoutPictureFG*}
\makeatother
%% hyper ref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1 %% noinfo
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \frac{y}{2a-x} & = \frac{2\frac{y}{x+a}}{1-\frac{y^2}{(x+a)^2}} \\
    \frac{1}{2a-x} & = \frac{ 2(x+a) }{ (x+a)^2- y^2 } \\
    2(x+a)(2a-x)   & = (x+a)^2- y^2 \\
        y^2        & = (x+a)^2- 2(x+a)(2a-x) \\
        y^2        & = (x+a) \left( x+a - 4a +2x \right) \\
        y^2        & = (x+a) \left( 3x - 3a \right)  \\
        y^2        & = 3(x+a) (x-a)  \\
        y^2        & = 3(x^2-a^2)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Used to work about a month ago,
then just stopped.

Comment: Delete you question. Take the time to make a mwe and then come back. Dumping some unfinished stuff like this is quite unfriendly.

Comment: Please provide a MWE that we can test. The problem might be an obsolete package, or a package that changed and you're using obsolete syntax. It'd easier to see in a short code rather than a very long log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Any hint would be useful...as I have changed nothing in the file....and it has about 30 packages loaded in the preable...

Comment: @Miyase Any hint would be useful...as I have changed nothing in the file....and it has about 30 packages loaded in the preable

Comment: No, I won't try to make guesses. 30 packages aren't much, and it will take you only a few minutes to remove some of them. So stop to dump your stuff on us and do your work first.

Comment: And we'd gladly provide hints if we could, but my crystal ball seems to be broken. I can't guess the content of your file if you don't provide it. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: reduce the mwe so that it loads at most three packages.

Comment: If you load the `currfile` package before the `doclicense` package, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

It is a very bad bug in `hyperxmp`. `hyperxmp` patches `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` from kvoptions to attach its code (*which it shouldn't do*), and as soon as two following packages try to use this command to set their keys it loops. Your problem can be reproduced in texlive 2021 too with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax %first package

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax %second package

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Your example loops after the update because hyperref now loads nameref earlier, and so a second package beside currfile appeared in your setup. The best you can do for now is to load doclicense late and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @hair-splitter , the problem seemed to have been caused by the packages `currfile` and `doclicense`.

Simply switch the order did solve my problem in this case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,scheme = plain]{ctexart}
%%% 28 April 2022
%%%%% packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
%% \usepackage{currfile} % works
\usepackage[type= {CC},modifier= {by-nc-nd},version= {4.0}]{doclicense}
\usepackage{currfile} % does not work
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \frac{y}{2a-x} & = \frac{2\frac{y}{x+a}}{1-\frac{y^2}{(x+a)^2}} \\
    \frac{1}{2a-x} & = \frac{ 2(x+a) }{ (x+a)^2- y^2 } \\
    2(x+a)(2a-x)   & = (x+a)^2- y^2 \\
        y^2        & = (x+a)^2- 2(x+a)(2a-x) \\
        y^2        & = (x+a) \left( x+a - 4a +2x \right) \\
        y^2        & = (x+a) \left( 3x - 3a \right)  \\
        y^2        & = 3(x+a) (x-a)  \\
        y^2        & = 3(x^2-a^2)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it shouldn't happen and it is a bug in hyperxmp.

Comment: I remember had some problems between `doclicense` and `hyperref` too last year, something to do with this `hyperxmp` as well.